# re-base concat is not a function

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

(I am using re-base, cant create re-base tag)
I am trying to get user input and then append it onto my state arrays: titles, descriptions and content of a blog and store it in firebase realtime database.

I checked other questions and made sure that my states are arrays so that concat would work.

```
handleEntry(titleInput, descriptionInput, contentInput) {
    this.setState({
        titles: this.state.titles.concat(titleInput),
        descriptions: this.state.descriptions.concat(descriptionInput),
        contents: this.state.contents.concat(contentInput)
    })
}
```

I thought that my state would be updated by instead has a TypeError:this.state.titles.concat is not a function

However, the error points it here at the full stop before syncState:

```
    this.contentsRef = base.syncState('contents', {
        context: this,
        state: 'contents'
    })
```

UPDATE: I'm not sure if this is the way to do it, but it works. Instead of assigning the state using the state's value, I used a placeholder then assigned it to the state.

```
    handleEntry(titleInput, descriptionInput, contentInput) {
    var titleHolder = [...this.state.titles].concat(titleInput);
    var descriptionHolder = [...this.state.descriptions].concat(descriptionInput);
    var contentHolder = [...this.state.contents].concat(contentInput);
    this.setState({
        titles: titleHolder,
        descriptions: descriptionHolder,
        contents: contentHolder
    })
}
```

Comment: you should not set state based on the values of the current state because they are asynchronous: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html

Comment: @cornel.raiu Thank you! I managed solve this one thanks to you. (But instead there is a "TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance" problem.)

Comment: Please update the code with your latest version

Comment: @cornel.raiu alright I just did. Sorry I'm very new to the community.